# Can we have a session termination trigger with Apache while using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, session

I came across a requirement where I want to trigger a script as soon as a session goes down. I'm creating a session with a life until client browser gets closed and my platform is PHP 5.6 on CentoS 7 and I'm using Apache as a web server and session is being saved in redis database.

Thank you for your kind support on this.

Regards
Mohtashim

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Jose, did you find some issue with my question? Btw, I'm not new at SO.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a kind of atexit() function in PHP for sessions. Short answer: it is not possible that way.
Maybe you can implement a program running on the server (via cron for example for running every minute or so) that check the files in "session.save_path" directory. That variable should be in your php.ini configuration file.
You will have to keep track of those files and then check when they are no longer present.
There is also a function called: session_save_path() in PHP that may be useful if you do this program in PHP.
Sorry I can't be more helpful here.. I am suggesting here things that I have not done.

Comment: Thanks Zsram, yes what you are saying makes very much sense and yes it can be greatly implemented with the help of database, but let's see if someone else has implemented same solution in some other way.

Comment: Sure. Although I don't see any other way to implement what you need because your php programs on the server can't know when a user has, for example, closed his browser. I believe then that the Apache PHP module on the server should be doing some sort of "session garbage collection", perhaps looking in the very same session.save_path directory for removing files from terminated sessions. You have to emulate that if I understood well your question. Regards.